# how to refer to 'this' in object`s property value?

Tags: javascript, object, this

```
var search = {
    form: $('search-form'),
    input: this.form.find('.search-input'), // 'this' undefined
    callback: function(){
        console.log(this.form) // 'this' not undefined
    }
}
```

Help me, please!
Sorry, my English not very good, but I'll try to explain my problem.
I can't select input element inside form of current object, because `this.form` undefined. Why it's undefined?

What is wrong in this code?

```
input: this.form.find('.search-input')
```

And how could I correct the above code?

Comment: The object doesn't exist at the time it is at definition, and hence can't be referred. A getter might be a solution, or just rewrite `$('search-form')`.

Comment: The `this` would refer to the context containing the `search` object. Not the object itself. Do you have a factory method to create these objects? You could set `input` then?

Comment: Show how you use `input` property

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `input` property to be a function instead:

```
var search = {
    form: $('search-form'),
    input: function() { 
       return this.form.find('.search-input') 
    }, 
    callback: function(){
        console.log(this.form) // 'this' not undefined
    }
}
```

Then call using `search.input()` to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

`$('search-form').find('.search-input')` - the only way to get it work. When you define your values, object doesn't exists yet, so you cannot refer to it. You can try to define object first, and then add `search.input = search.form.find('.search-input')`